# Operator fault in query

Tags: sql

```
SELECT siteapplications.Application, Count(visits.VisitId) AS CountOfVisitId
FROM visits, siteapplications
WHERE visits.SiteApplicationId=siteapplications.ApplicationID and Month([visits.VisitTime)]=month and Year([visits.VisitTime])=year
GROUP BY siteapplications.Application
ORDER BY CountOfVisitId DESC;
```

I get a operator fault and when I click ok Group by is highlighted??

Can anyone help, thx all

Comment: Consider a better title. It is vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
and Month([visits.VisitTime)]
```

Your paren closing is off